# Post data (Webclient / Webrequest) to HTTPS page

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest, webclient

I've tried to rebuild the folloging very simple Post methode:

https:/XYZ.com/v01/example.html

At Winforms client it works perfekt like this:

```
WC = New Net.WebClient
Dim reqparm As New Specialized.NameValueCollection
reqparm.Add("DomainName", "XYZarco.com")
reqparm.Add("PIN", "1111")
Dim responsebytes() As Byte = WC.UploadValues(uri, "POST", reqparm) 'works
Dim responsebody As String = (New Text.UTF8Encoding).GetString(responsebytes) 'works
```

But on Windows Phone 7.1 it does not work because library does not support UploadValues. After research I found that:

```
Dim U As String = "https://XYZ.com/v01/api.asp"
        Dim uri As New Uri(U, UriKind.Absolute)

        If WC Is Nothing Then
            WC = New WebClient
            'WC.Headers("HttpRequestHeader.ContentType") = "    text/html"
            WC.Headers("HttpRequestHeader.ContentType") = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            WC.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
        End If
        Dim Params As String = "DomainName=xyz.com&PIN=1111"
        WC.Headers("HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength") = Params.Length.ToString
        WC.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST", Params)
```

But data are not posted. Response means: . ERROR 01, DomainName not correct, Please insert the Gold website like Domain.com

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WC.Headers("HttpRequestHeader.ContentType")
```

HttpRequestHeader is an enumeration. Use it without quotes:

```
WC.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType)
```

Comment: THANK YOU !! I was completely on wrong track. You made my day!